# Vk bot как среагировать на вступление в беседу?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравстуйте. Бот вк на php, callback API. (5,81) 
Задача: Заставить бота отправлять сообщение в беседу после вступления в неё человека. 
Вот как я это делаю, когда хочу просто ответить на сообщение:

```
$message = $data->object->text;
if ($data->type == 'message_new')
{
  if ($message == "привет!" )  
    {
      $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "Hello there!");  
       }
 }
```

И вот нужно ответить не при сообщении от пользователя, а при вступлении его в беседу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался сам.

```
$beseda = $data->object->action; 
if (isset($beseda->type) and $beseda->type == 'chat_invite_user') 
{ 
$vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "Добро пожаловать"); 
}
```